# When are there continuous families of pull-backs of a discrete cohomology class of a compact Lie group?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-cohomology

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a compact Lie group. Then define $H^n(\mathcal{G},\mathrm{U}(1))$ to be the cohomology of measurable cochains $\mathcal{G}^{\times n} \to \mathrm{U}(1)$ with the usual coboundary map. In particular $H^n(\mathcal{G}, \mathrm{U}(1)) \cong H^{n+1}(\mathcal{G}, \mathbb{Z})$, so it is discrete.

Now, for any homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^{ n} \to \mathcal{G}$, there is an induced map $\varphi^{*} : H^{n}(\mathcal{G}, \mathrm{U}(1)) \to H^{n}(\mathbb{Z}^{ n}, \mathrm{U}(1)) \cong \mathrm{U}(1)$. I am wondering, what are examples of groups $\mathcal{G}$ and classes $\alpha \in H^n(\mathcal{G}, \mathrm{U}(1))$ such that the set

$$ S = \{ \varphi^*(\alpha) : \varphi \, \mbox{is any homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^{n} \to \mathcal{G} $} \} \subseteq \mathrm{U}(1)$$

satisfies $S = \mathrm{U}(1)$ (and in particular is *not* discrete)?

The only one I could think is for $n=1$, with $\mathcal{G} = \mathrm{U}(1)$ and you take the class $\alpha$ to be the generator of $H^1(\mathrm{U}(1), \mathrm{U}(1)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. Then there is a continuous family of homomorphisms $\varphi_\theta : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathrm{U}(1)$ and indeed this allows us to show that $S = \mathrm{U}(1)$.